# Event wont fire, but its working from console

Tags: jquery

This is strange. I have simple code that wont fire, but when I run it from browser console it works fine...

This code should work without problem:

```
$("#clear_filter").on("click", function() {
        $('div#results>div').removeAttr('style');
        $('div#results>div').removeClass('filter');
        $('#filter_category').css('display', '');
    });
```

It's wrapped inside dom ready along with bunch of other code...

Has anyone encountered similar issue?

Comment: How do you know it won't fire? Are you sure this code is called before you try clicking? Are you sure the element you're clicking on really has the id `clear_filter`?

Comment: In addition to @Dan's questions, are you pretty sure this code is inside the ready event listener?

Comment: Maybe `#clear_filter` added dynamically to the page. Try `$("body").on("click", "#clear_filter, function()  { /* .... */ });` instead, to use event delegation (you can substitute `body` for a closer ancestor)

Comment: @Dan because Im clicking on element with that id and nothing, but when I input code in console it works. Its really that id, I double checked. I was hopping there is some obvious issue

Comment: @RenatoZannon that's it! it is added dynamically. Since I'm doing js and jquery for only few weeks now, I still don't understand implications fully. Can you explain to me what happen here?

Comment: @user3275701 If it's added dynamically, what's the parent id of `#clear_filter` then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments on the question, it seems like the `#clear_filter` element is being added dynamically to the page (i.e. it is added after the page has loaded).

**tl;dr**: You need to setup the event handler after the element is on the page, or use event delegation.

Let's walk through what the `.on("click")` call does:

- `$("#clear_filter")` - find the element whose id is `clear_filter`
- `on("click", function() { /* .... */ })` - set a event handler for when the `click` event happens on it.

Note that the element needs to be found *before* the event handler is bound to it. If the element is not on the page when this code runs, it won't bind anywhere, and the handler won't run (even if the element is added afterwards).

To solve this, you can either wait for the element to be added to the page before binding the click handler (to do that, you need to know when the element is added - this will be specific to your site/application), or you can use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

```
$("body").on("click", "#clear_filter", function() {
  /* ... */
});
```

Here, the handler is not bound to `#clear_filter`, but to the page's `<body>` element (any ancestor of `#clear_filter` would do - I'm using `body` because I don't know more of your HTML).

When a `click` happens on `#clear_filter`, the event bubbles all the way to the `body`, and the event is handled there.

Comment: Whoa... beat me by a few seconds! +1.

Comment: Thank you on explanation Renato. My mistake was that I assumed that when I set event handler for an element, it just sits there and waits for that element to be clicked in this case. But really it is blinded when the page is loaded and at that moment particular element didn't exist on page. This is very important thing I had to learn, thank you again

Answer (score 2):

If your HTML elements are added dynamically after page load, then you must assign [**delegated event listeners**](https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).

You didn't give me the immediate parent id/class of `#clear_filter` in the comments, but this code should work, too.

```
$("body").on("click", "#clear_filter", function() {
    $('div#results>div').removeAttr('style');
    $('div#results>div').removeClass('filter');
    $('#filter_category').css('display', '');
});
```